# Json to Uitableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm loading Json into an NSDictionary and the output is below. I'm just not to sure on how to parse it so I can insert it into a UItableview so the first row will say 6 street 10950 and the second row will say Munch lane 11730 and so on. Thank you for your help.

```
(
    {
    "address_line1" = "6 street";
    "zipcode" = 10950;
},
    {
    "address_line1" = "Munch lane";
    "zipcode" = 11730;
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you ran it through a json parser such as NSJSONSerialization, you now have an NSArray of NSDictionarys. Implement the UITableViewDatasource method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your UITableView or UITableViewController class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString     *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell     *cell = nil;
    NSDictionary        *addressDictionary = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if ([indexPath row] <= [[self jsonAddressArray] count]){
        rowDictionary = [[self jsonAddressArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        if (rowDictionary != nil){
            cell.textLabel.text = [rowDictionary objectForKey:@"address_line1"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [rowDictionary objectForKey:@"zipcode"];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

(This assumes you set the property 'jsonAddressArray' to your parsed JSON data.)

This puts the address line 1 on the first line of the cell, and the zip code on the second line of the cell. If you want both on one line, change the cell style to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, combine the two strings and set `cell.textLabel.text` to that string.

Answer (score 0):

At first, this json should be loaded in an NSArray, it will be easier to use after that.

Then you can simply load it like that in your tableview data source :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myArray.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    NSDictionary *cellDict = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [cellDict objectForKey:@"address_line1"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [cellDict objectForKey:@"zipcode"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hey Philippe97. So imported you three methods into my project but its crashing on this line NSDictionary *cellDict = [luckyNumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]. I'm initializing the array in the view did load method and the data is being sent to it like this     luckyNumbers = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData                                                        options:kNilOptions error:&error]. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind got it. I just loaded the luckyNumbers array into another array and it worked. Thank you!